# Make answer highlighting fade to red instead of white for deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, highlighting

This is a really minor issue, but it bothers me more than it should.

When you follow a link to an answer ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/502381)) the answer's background flashes to yellow and slowly fades back to white. This works fine.

When you have 10k+ reputation and you follow a link to a deleted answer ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227942/502381), you need 10k+ on SO) it does the same (fade from yellow to white) but after the animation has finished it "snaps" back to deleted answer's red background. The same applies to [comments within deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227942#comment14749888_11227942).

Could the highlighting animation be made to fade from yellow to the post's actual background, which is red for deleted posts?

Comment: We disagree about colors (yellow vs. orange, and red vs. gray), but we both agree about this feature request. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray I always thought "what colours are they talking about, they're totally different" - until I visited from a different box (with a CRT monitor, don't know if that matters), and, lo and behold, yellow, red(dish), just like people wrote.